# unable to apply css on custom radio button

Tags: html, css

I am creating custom radio button and did apply the css and it looks good but when i am clicking on it, doesn't change the appearance.

Here is my HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="single_multiple_flag" class="radio" id="single_venue" value="single_venue" checked="checked"> 
<label for="single_venue">Single Venue</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="single_multiple_flag" class="radio" id="multiple_venue" value="multiple_venue"> 
<label for="multiple_venue">Multiple Venues</label>
```

here is my css:

```
.ugc_block .ele1 input[type=radio]{opacity:0;}
.ugc_block .ele1 label::before{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../images/check.png") no-repeat scroll -6px -5px / 375px auto;
  content: "";
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: -45px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 27px;
}

.ugc_block .ele1 input[type=radio]:checked + .ugc_block .ele1 label::before{
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../images/checked.png") no-repeat scroll -103px -5px / 375px auto;
  content: "";
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: -45px;
  margin-top: -3px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 27px;
}
```

Comment: You are doing wrong in your second css. 
instead of this:

`.ugc_block .ele1 input[type=radio]:checked + .ugc_block .ele1 label::before`

you should use this:

`.ugc_block .ele1 input[type=radio]:checked + label::before`

this will work

Comment: oh yes!!! You said it right. Even @helenys did it correct and same thing. Thanks both of you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell where the mistake is since you did not attach working code to test. I have tested it with simple example and it should work, keeping in mind that your css selector are working properly.

Here is the simple example I tested with:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
label::before{
  content: "";
  background-color:red;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  margin-left:-40px;
  
}

input[type=radio]{
  margin-left:30px;
  opacity:0;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label::before{
  content: "";
  background-color:green;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30px;
  margin-left:-40px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<input type="radio" name="single_multiple_flag" class="radio" id="single_venue" value="single_venue" checked="checked"> 

<label for="single_venue">Single Venue</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<input type="radio" name="single_multiple_flag" class="radio" id="multiple_venue" value="multiple_venue"> 

<label for="multiple_venue">Multiple Venues</label> 


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The numbers following rgba are values for Red, Green, Blue and the Opacity, respectively. You are setting your background to 0 opacity, so you won't be able to see it.

```
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Without seeing a Plunker of this, I am assuming if you remove the last 0 or change it to 1.0 you should be able to see the background color and image.

Comment: it's not working. I can see the image for the radio button when it is loaded but unable to change it when clicked.